# Impact of AWS SWF connectivity on currently executing workflows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am curious to understand the loss of connectivity with AWS SWF on currently executing workflows. Could someone please help me understand.
I understand there would be timeout of deciders and workers. But not sure of the exact behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity worker that waits on a poll will get an error and is expecting to keep retrying until connectivity is back. Activity worker that has completed a task is expected to keep retrying to complete the task until the task is expired.

Workflow worker that waits on a poll will get an error and is expecting to keep retrying until connectivity is back. Workflow worker that has completed a decision task can retry to complete it until it is expired. After it is expired the decision task is automatically rescheduled and is available for poll as soon as connectivity is back.

Scheduled activity that wasn't picked up for a specified *schedule to start* timeout is automatically failed. Its failure is recorded into workflow history and the new decision is scheduled.

Picked up activity that wasn't completed for a specified *start to complete* timeout is automatically failed. Its failure is recorded into workflow history and the new decision is scheduled.